# Define $\partial(n\mid x) = \partial(q_0 \cdots q_i \mid x) = \sum_{j=0}^i (-1)^i q_j (\frac{n}{q_j} \mid x)$. What does homology measure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, divisor-sum

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and let $M = \{ f : \Bbb{N} \to R \}$ be the $R$-module of arithmetic functions into $R$.

A basis for $M$ is $(d \mid \cdot) : d \in \Bbb{N}$ where $(d\mid n) = 1 \iff d \mid n$ and is $0$ otherwise.

I'm wondering if you take $M_n = \{ f \in M : f(x) = \sum_{d \in \Bbb{N} \\ \Omega(d) = n}f_d\cdot(d \mid x), \ f_d \in R\}$.

And define $\partial_i : M_i \to M_{i-1}$,

$$
\partial_i (n \mid \cdot) = \partial(q_0 \cdots q_i \mid \cdot) = \sum_{j = 0}^i(-1)^j q_j(\frac{d}{q_j}\mid \cdot)
$$

and extend linearly to all of $M_i$.  These form differential chain maps.  Check by comoposing twice i.e. $\partial^2(pqr\mid \cdot)$ and seeing that everything cancels to $0$.

Also check that $\partial_1(f) = \sum_{q \in \Bbb{P}} f_q q$.  So that the condition $f \in \ker \partial_1 \iff \sum_{q} f_q q = 0$.  Let's consider $M$ such that we only look at functions that have finitely many non-zero coefficients.

Then $f \in Z_1 = \ker \partial_1$ iff and only if $f(x) = \sum_{q \in \Bbb{P}} f_q(q\mid x)$ and $\sum_{q} f_q q = 0$.

> I'm wondering in English what the homology here at $M_1$ counts and say $R = \Bbb{Z}$.

$$
q(p\mid\cdot ) - p(q\mid\cdot) = \partial_2(pq\mid \cdot), \\
\forall p \leq q, \ p,q \in \Bbb{P}
$$
is in the boundary submodule $B_1 \leqslant Z_1$.  Then ?

---

**Attempt.**  Let $R = \Bbb{Z}$.

$$
5 - 3 - 2 = 0 \implies (5\mid \cdot)  - (3\mid \cdot) - (2\mid \cdot) \in Z_1 \\
$$

Each $p(q\mid \cdot) - q(p\mid \cdot) \in B_1$, so that for all $2 \leq q$ we have that $2(q\mid \cdot) = q(2\mid \cdot)$ modulo $B_1$.  Which means:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{q}f_q(q\mid x) = \sum_{q \neq 2} (f_q)_{(2)}\cdot(q\mid\cdot) + \left((f_2)_{(2)} +\sum_{q} q\left\lfloor\frac{f_q}{2}\right\rfloor\right) (2\mid \cdot) \pmod {B_1}
$$

So we can say that the $H_1 = Z_1/B_1 \approx \bigoplus_{q \in \Bbb{P}, \\ q \neq 2} \Bbb{Z}_2 (q \mid x) \oplus \Bbb{Z}(2\mid \cdot)$

Comment: I think the homology is zero at $M_1$.

Comment: $$
\partial_1(\sum_{q \in \Bbb{P}}(q\mid \cdot)f_q) = 0 \iff \sum_q f_qq = 0
$$

Since $B_1 \ni \partial_2(pq\mid\cdot ) = p(q\mid\cdot) - q(p\mid\cdot)$ for all primes $p, q$ with $p \leq q$ which means $2(q\mid\cdot) = q(2\mid \cdot) \pmod {B_1}$.  Let $R = \Bbb{Q}$, then each $(q\mid \cdot) = \frac{q}{2}(2\mid \cdot)$ so we can of course rewrite:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{q \in \Bbb{P}}f_q(q\mid x) \in Z_1 \implies \left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{q \in \Bbb{P}}f_qq \right)(2 \mid \cdot) = 0 \pmod {B_1}
$$

Therefore, homology at $M_1$ is trivial.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez the difference of this one is that it has a $(pq\mid \cdot) \mapsto p(q\mid \cdot) - q(p\mid \cdot)$ or namely the prime factor tagging along with each of the output basis vectors.  So you drop a prime in the basis vector, but it shows up as a coefficient.

Comment: Any buddy have any idea?